# Debouncing ember search input

Tags: search, ember.js, frontend, debouncing

I want to add debounce to my search input in ember app.
I'm having problems with using [debounce method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce).

Here's how my search looks like:

```
{{input type="search"
         placeholder="Search by XYZ"
         value=search
         id="search"
}}
```

My route file:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
    search:{refreshModel: true}
}
```

My controller file:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    search: "",
```

Comment: you are missing `queryParams:['search']` in controller. it's just a note it will not help in your issue

Answer (score 5):

Implementing your desired behaviour debouncing with existing input helper is quite difficult since it will update value immediately.

1. So I will encourage you to use normal input html element and use keyUp event to listen and manually set value inside debounce method.

Inside controller,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams:['easyFilter'],
  easyFilter:'',
  setEasyFilterLazily(value){
    this.set('easyFilter',value);
  },
  actions:{    
     handleEasyFilterEntry(value){   
      Ember.run.debounce(this, this.setEasyFilterLazily,value, 500);
    }
  }
});
```

[Created twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4cacd31248925fee2efc2dcd7e3f9ed2?openFiles=controllers.users.js%2C) for demonstration.

2. One more interesting options are using [ember-concurrency addon](https://github.com/machty/ember-concurrency).
   Need to use perform helper instead of action helper,

`<input type="text" value={{filterValue}} oninput={{perform triggerToUpdateFilter value='target.value'}}>`

and

```
triggerToUpdateFilter: task(function*(value) {
  yield timeout(1000); //here it will wait for 1000 ms before setting
  this.set('easyFilter',value);
}).restartable(),
```

As this task is `restartable` so it will restart when you type fast within 1000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
search: computed('', {
  set(key, value) {
    debounce(this, this.setValue, value, 500);
  }
})
```

This worked for me, looks like this overrides the default setter for search.